# Issue with attachment in SharePoint 2013 Discussion Board

Tags: discussion-board, attachments

I am having an issue with attachment to a discussion in a discussion board.

When I try to attach a file, the file appears in the rich text editor and when I hit backspace I am able to delete letter by letter in the file name.

The file is no more clickable. Please let me know if this is a known issue in SharePoint 2013? If not please provide a fix for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

is the attachment a TXT file? if so it is likely. I attach excel spreadsheets and images and I have the attachment as attachment

Comment: The file i used to check was a text file. I even tried images and excel files also, I see the same issue.

Comment: When I said txt file I meant *.txt (a file made with notepad). What do you see with an image? there is no text in an image

Comment: Susan, Looks like i wast able to convey the issue properly.So I am giving a further detailed explanation of the issue below.                                                                                                                        After uploading the file the file name with its extension appears in the rich text editor with a hyper link to download the file. (ex:mypicture.jpg). i click on the rich text editor and hit backspace at the end of the file name. I delete one letter in the file ext. Now i see the file name as mypicture.jp without a hyperlink.Hope this explains the issue.